# Template Driven Form Validation on Text area

Tags: css, angular, validation, angular-material

I added a text area to my angular form. all the input/mat-select fields work fine with the requried attribute. For the `textarea` I added a custom class to show a red border. For some reason when I click the clear button the two input fields automatically applies its own red class but my custom class for the `texarea`a does not unless it has been touched. Which is fine but does not match the styles of the input fields. How do I apply the same validation styles to the text area: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpefsn

```
.text-error.ng-invalid.ng-touched{
  border: 1px solid #b00b00;
}
```

If you click on the clear button initially when the stack blitz loads you will see the two inputfields turn red but not the `textarea`. This is because I have the `ngtouched` class. But if I remove it then the textarea will initially be red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mark the `textarea` [form control](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) as `touched` when clicking on the clear button:

```
<textarea #txt="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="questionText" required ...></textarea>

<button (click)="clear(); txt.control.markAsTouched();" ...>Clear</button>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpefsn-yxt4bz?file=app%2Fform-field-theming-example.html) for a demo.

Comment: How do I marke it as touched from `.ts` file in a function?

Comment: You could pass the `ngModel` or the `FormControl` to the event handler: `(click)="clear(txt.control)"`, and call `markAsTouched` inside the method. Another possibility would be to refer to the `textarea` with `@ViewChild`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would to just use matInput with the textarea

```
<mat-form-field>
  <textarea matInput ...></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

then you would have the same style for all the input fields. And material would apply red because it is required.

The harder way, if you want the textarea to be of different style could be to manually add a class to the textarea field.

.ts file:

```
public cleared = false;
...
clear() {
  ..
  this.cleared = true;
}
```

and in your html:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="inputValue" [class.custom_invalid_form_class]="cleared && inputValue.length > 0"></textarea>
```

Comment: Text adding matInput to a textarea just breaks it

Comment: @Flash - Engam's suggestion seems to work well. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpefsn-aeznyz?file=app/form-field-theming-example.html).

Comment: I will double check but in your stackblitz the borders are not showing initially. I guess i can add some additional css to fix it though

Comment: @Flash - The borders aren't meant to be shown as per the Angular Material design.

Comment: oh really for a text area?

Comment: Remember to put textarea inside a mat-form-field element. Then you should get a bottom border to it. If you want the inputs to stand out a bit more you could apply appearance="outline" or appearance="fill" like this: <mat-form-field appearance="outline">...</mat-form-field>

Comment: I ended up going this route since I wanted the native textarea: https://stackblitz.com/edit/textarea-validation

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing the red border here for the other fields except for the `textarea` is because the other fields are getting their `CSS` from `.mat-form-field-invalid`. The `.mat-form-field-invalid` gets added to your `mat-form-field` because of this class which gets added when you submit the form without filling the required fields.

So do the same for your `textarea`, remove the `text-error` class as it's not required and add the `matInput` directive. Then just wrap your `textarea` in a `mat-form-field` like  below

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput name="questionText" cols="35" rows="8" placeholder="Question Text" [(ngModel)]="questionText" required></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-textarea-mat-form-field).

Comment: Just Tried but I get this error `mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.` Do you have a working stackblizt

Comment: @Flash - I have added it to my answer.

Comment: See the first example in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#-code-lt-input-gt-code-and-code-lt-textarea-gt-code-attributes). The second input field (Leave a comment) is a `textarea` and it doesn't contain borders.

Comment: Thanks I will get back to you 2mrw apprecuate the help

Comment: Thanks this way works, but because I wanted the native text area this way worked best: https://stackblitz.com/edit/textarea-validation

Comment: Sure the design is up to you at the end of the day. I just wanted to make sure you were aware of what the standard material `textarea` looks like :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the

```
<ion-textarea></ion-textarea>
```

instead of the native

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

in order to see validation results like with the

```
<ion-input></ion-input>
```

Comment: Thanks I will test this out